# Google Play won't publish my app because

Tags: android, google-play

" Upload failed
You need to use a different package name because "com.nanoconverter.zlab" already exists in Google Play. "

This is what Google Play says when i try to upload my apk. I am stuck over there and i do not know what to do . I've tried to edit the AndroidManifest.xml and also to Refactor (Shift + F6) the package name ( on build->java->"package name" ) but the Google Play seems to keep me only the same note. I don't know what is wrong with my apk. but when i open the Project i do not see any "com.nanoconverter.zlab".
Please help me!

Comment: package name you have used is already used in play store.

Comment: yes i know this but how do i change it ?

Comment: what IDE you use to create Android APP?

Comment: What is your root package name

Comment: are you using android studio?

Comment: Yes , Android Studio

Comment: I've also edited the build.gradle file and it keeps to appears.

Answer (score 1):

This app package is match with your package name, below is link

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nanoconverter.zlab&hl=en

Just go to in your development tool and rename than upload it this will work.

Comment: Thanks , i ve just got this app purchased and i see that that pr*ck fooled me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, after refactoring and changing the package name, you need to change your application id in your app's "build.gradle" file.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.yourapp"
}
```

Comment: I did this , i don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

If applicationId change don't work then the most easy way is to create a new Project with a new Id. Then copy & past your files.  I don't find any other solution yet. And then finally generate a new key store.